# Clarification wanted re. C++ type_traits

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

It appears that to test for const-ness, one must test the template-parameter, but to test for rvalue-ness, one must test an actual parameter. (This is using VC++ 2012.) This code illustrates what I mean:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void f(T& x) {
    cout << "f() is_const<T> and is_const<decltype<x)>" << endl;
    cout << is_const<T>::value << endl; // Prints 1 when arg is const
    cout << is_const<decltype(x)>::value << endl; // Prints 0 when arg is const
}

template<class T>
void g(T&& x) {
    cout << "g() is_const<T> and is_const<decltype<x)>" << endl;
    cout << is_const<T>::value << endl; // Prints 0 when arg is const
    cout << is_const<decltype(x)>::value << endl; // Prints 0 when arg is cons
    cout << "g() is_rvalue_reference<T> and is_rvalue_reverence<decltype(x)>" <<endl;
    cout << is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << endl; // Prints 0 when arg is rvlaue
    cout << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(x)>::value << endl; // Prints 1 when arg is rvalue
}

int main()
{
    const std::string str;
    f(str); // const argument
    cout << endl;
    g(std::string("")); // rvalue argument
    return 0;
}
```

I am struggling to understand why that is. Can someone explain, or point me to an article that explains it? If need be, I will dig into the C++11 standard. Anyone know the pertinent sections?

Comment: `const` is part of a *type*. "Rvalue" is a value category, which is part of an *expression*. Two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you're misunderstanding things. `x` will never be `const` in any of those examples, simply because there are no `const` reference types (you can't change what a reference refers to anyways). In `is_const<T>` you're basically ignoring that you declared `x` as `T&`.

A similar misunderstanding is at work for the rvalue ref test. The `T` in `T&&` (which is called a universal reference, btw) will be deduced as `U&` when you pass an lvalue and as `U` when you pass an rvalue. When testing `is_rvalue_reference<T>`, you're ignoring again that you declared `x` as `T&&`. When testing `is_const<T>`, you didn't account for the fact that `T` will be a reference, which, as said above, can never be `const`.

The correct tests for `g` would be

- `std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value` and
- `std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value`

Comment: Thanks. It is good that I am not easily embarrassed, or this question might have done it. One thing that confused me, I guess, is that is_const<T>::value is never true for a reference, although all references are, by their nature, constant. That is the main difference between a pointer and a reference. Const pointers must be declared as such. I tried declaring a reference as const. VC++ 2012 told me that is an "anachronism". In the VC++ 2012 headers, there is a specialization for is_const<T&> that derives from false_type. So a reference is_const never, although it is constant always.

Comment: @Jive: You make it sound like you think the standard would make sense. :)

Comment: I gave up on that in the late 80's. I even questioned the wisdom of adding references at all. What is wrong with const pointers? Of course that was before templates. With a pointer, the syntax makes it clear that you are dealing with a reference (in the common sense of the word). Not so with "references." BTW, on second thought, I believe VC++ used a different word than "anachronism." "Antiquated" I think it was.

Comment: @Jive: References are a very much needed concept in C++. How else would operator overloading work?